# Video Card needs additional mounting support

Tags: graphics-card

We are creating a fairly decent system with crossfire.

The issue we are having is apparently the video cards are physically to heavy to be supported purely by the motherboard and case mounts.

Whenever we have the case horizontal everything works fine however when we bring the case upright the computer stops working.

Relevant Info:
Video Cards (2) - Sapphire 5870 (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102856)
MotherBoard - Asus M4A79T Deluxe
Case - CoolerMaster 922 HAF

To me it looks as if an additional support bracket that could hold up the end of the card would be required (included with the viideo cards!!!)

Does anyone have any experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not help but I believe some boards will have a videocard retention lock on the slot.  This locks the tab at the "back" of the card in the slot and that keeps it from moving.  There used to be an optional adapter to do this on early AGP cards and then it seems to have become standard.  The image here shows one [MB image](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1789)  It appears your ASUS board has a slightly different locking tab.

Comment: The retention lock does not appear to support anything

Comment: I believe it should snap behind the L-shaped tab at the rear of the card. The small projection/knob on the curved bit of plastic would fit into the gap. On the other images I found, it shows a lock more like a DIMM lock. I can see why you would have this issue and one would think it would be a well known issue

Comment: WE used a ahem small c clamp