# Large video card bends under own weight

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, case

My [ASUS GTX 770](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/GTX770DC2OC2GD5/) card is so long and heavy that it bends under its own weight. The following picture is not mine, but my situation looks exactly like it:

[image: hanging video card]

The bending has already become permanent, because it remains when I lay the PC on its side.

- Is this harmful? I assume it's not, because otherwise ASUS would have fixed it?
- Still, can I do something to properly support the thing, other than a mini-Superman? My case is a [Corsair C70](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-c70-mid-tower-gaming-case-military-green).

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: [Video Card needs additional mounting support](http://superuser.com/questions/110173/video-card-needs-additional-mounting-support)

Comment: You could try tying some (insulated) wire around the screw-hole to the right of the graphics card then feed that through a free fan mount / cable management loop at the top of your case, pull it tight and tie. This might be better attached to the hard drive cage (though it would have to be **really** tight) if you have a large CPU cooler or prefer a cleaner look

Comment: I think Superman is a perfect fix...! :)

Comment: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?p=1038606884#post1038606884

Comment: Not sure how elegant of a solution you want but I found this: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1678770/graphics-card-heavy-solutions-support.html

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine has used this technique, which worked really well:

Grab two or three cable ties. Loop one over the power connectors on the right hand side of the GPU. If not the power connectors, loop through a solid part of the card like the plastic frame of the fan.

Use the other one or two cable ties to form a chain from the GPU to the top of the case, and loop that around something on the case (most cases will have somewhere you can thread the cable ties through). Tighten gently so that it gives it support, but doesn't pull it out of the socket. Clip off the excess on the cable ties so it looks a bit neater.

It's ghetto, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Harmful?  Possibly.  I think you've already identified the "harm".. and that's to the adjacent slot.

Of course, the "solution" is orientation... but since the damage is already done, the solution is non-conductive standoffs of some kind.  Even so, it's not a great solution because of the pressure that might be place on the adjacent card through the stand-off.  But I have used a rubber foot before as my standoff before.  Maybe not the most elegant solution, but since you'll see this on other double-decker mezzanine style setups, it's not uncommon.